# Invalid Binary in ItunesConnect on Xamarin Project

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store-connect

My Issue
Supported by the Xamarin guidance here http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution_overview/publishing_to_the_app_store/ I used the App Loader tool (recently downloaded version 3) and uploaded my .ipa file. Everything indicates success but after a few minutes, it moves from “uploaded” to “invalid binary” 
I have checked stackoverflow and done a few suggestions ive double-checked all my image files and the build for 64 bit etc. Any help you can provide is appreciated.

Well since I dont have a 10 reputation I cannot post pics and i can only do one link, so I am going to upload this to my blog, I appreciate any help i can get please.

See complete issue explained here - http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2015/03/13/troubleshooting-itunesconnect-invalid-binary-with-xamarin-project/

Comment: In your screenshots you show the "supported architecture" of your iOS build to be for armv7. Does xamarin support arm64 like xcode does?

Comment: Yes, the past few releases are purported to do that. and their guidance told me to make sure that option was selected. thanks for your feedback & question

Answer (score 0):

I've hit this issue twice, including a few days ago.  In both cases the cause was that I included a bundle resource file (of my own proprietary format and definition) with the *.app extension.  For some reason, Apple's validation choked on this.  The hint was that the auto-generated email sent by iTunes Connect said something about requiring the zip extension.  Red herring error message, but it jogged my memory that *.app is a "special" extension I can't use for my own stuff.

Just to be clear, this *.app file that caused an issue was buried inside my overall *.ipa file and its *.app directory.  So you still need the standard format, you just need to be careful not to use Apple's extensions for your own proprietary data.